# Umbraco with KeyCloak

Tags: asp.net-web-api, umbraco7, keycloak, kong, keycloak-services

I have a Keycloak 3.4 instance installed up and running on my windows 10 machine. I have created an MVC application by following this link https://github.com/dylanplecki/KeycloakOwinAuthentication/wiki/ASP.NET-MVC-Tutorial. It is working fine. I want to achieve the same in Umbraco. But I am getting issues of DLL compatibilities and several other issues.

My aim is:

1. When I login in front end Umbraco login page(NOT backend), I should be redirected to Keycloak user login page.
2. Upon successful login in Keycloak, I should be directly redirected by passing login page to the Umbraco Home page which comes up after successful login in login page.
3. Once i am at home page of umbraco site, I have some pages which are calling the web api.
4. For web api management, I have Kong 0.11 installed. I want that when i call API from umbraco page, it should be validated by Kong using the token which Keycloak generated.

Please let me know if anybody has worked on such a scenario or project. Or if anybody can guide how it can be done based on their past experience.

Comment: Any progress with your scenario, @Varun? Have you been able to integrate Keycloak with Umbraco?

Comment: @Pavel Yes Iwas able to install it. Thanks